# Transformation between multi_array and array_view in Boost.MultiArray

Tags: c++, boost

My question is related to Boost.MultiArray class. I understand how to convert a `multi_array` object into a `array_view` object as the following codes show:

```
        int my_row = 5;
        int my_col = 7;
        boost::multi_array<int,2> my_matrix(boost::extents[my_row][my_col]);
        int *b = new int [my_row*my_col];
        int loop = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<my_row; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<my_col; j++)
            {
                loop = loop+1;
                my_matrix[i][j]=loop;
            }
        }

        std::cout<<"The  matrix"<<std::endl;
        for (int i=0; i<my_row; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<my_col; j++)
                std::cout<<my_matrix[i][j]<<"       ";
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }

        int new_row = 3;
        int new_col = 4;
        boost::multi_array<int,2>::array_view<2>::type my_view = 
            my_matrix[boost::indices
            [boost::multi_array<int,2>::index_range(0,new_row,1)]
            [boost::multi_array<int,2>::index_range(0,new_col,1)]
            ];

        std::cout<<"The view"<<std::endl;
        for (int i=0; i<new_row; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<new_col; j++)
                std::cout<<my_view[i][j]<<"     ";
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
```

My question is since the `array_view` object is very similar to `multi_array` object is there a way to transform the `array_view` object into a `multi_array` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array_class) has these constructors that take an `array_view`:

```
multi_array(const const_array_view<NumDims>::type& x);
multi_array(const array_view<NumDims>::type& x);
```

You can construct a `multi_array` from your `array_view` with code like this:

```
boost::multi_array<int,2> array_from_view(my_view);
```

Note that the new `multi_array` has separate storage from the view and original array.